# Ubuntu 11.04 Startup Applicatation vs /etc/init.d

Tags: ubuntu, startup, init

**Is there any difference between these two methods for application to start on boot?**  I need an application to start *before* a logon occurs and am questioning whether or not Ubuntu's Startup Application menu will accomplish this for me.  Otherwise, I can put a startup script in the init.d but then have to find some way of remebering thats where I stuck it (not be confused with /etc/rc.local which does not seem to work in Ubuntu 11.04) I have no other way of verifying that in fact the program is running without logging in at this time. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a big difference between those. What you can setup in the "Startup Applications" menu are all applications run after the user logs on into his/her desktop environment. And scripts under `/etc/init.d` are *system startup scripts* - they affect (almost) everything that is loaded from the moment your system finishes the kernel stage of booting (when `init` program is executed with `PID=1`).